# Information gets rendered before supplied by Redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an eCommerce Store with React, Redux and Firebase (Firestore + Storage).
In the **App** Component the information gets fetched from Firebase and dispatched. Then the action **Fetch_Products_Pending** and after the API Call is completed **Fetch_Products_Success** are dispatched.

My UI component renders the information from the Firestore before the **Fetch_Products_Success** action dispatched. I don't understand where it gets this information, because the only way is through the **fetchData** function in the App component.

[image]

So the component renders with the information it has before **Fetch_Products_Success** is complete, therefore without the URL for the image. After **Fetch_Products_Success** it doesn't rerender although the props change (because the URL is now fetched).

If I reroute to the page, the images get shown properly.

**App.js**

```js
const App = props => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const storageRef = storage.ref();
    const arr = [];
    dispatch(fetchProductsPending());

//API Call to fetch information from Firestore

    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        await firestore
          .collection("necklaces")
          .get()
          .then(function(querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
              arr.push(doc.data());
              
            });
          });

//Async forEach loop

          const asyncForEach = async (array, callback) => {
            for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
              await callback(array[index], index, array)
            }
          }

//Adding the URL to the products object that is afterwards saved in the Redux store[![enter image description here][1]][1]

          const start = async () => {
            await asyncForEach(arr, async (item) => {

              await storageRef.child(`images/${item.name}/1.png`).getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {       
                return (
                  item.url = url
                  )
              });

          })
        }
          start();

        dispatch(fetchProductsSuccess(arr));

      } catch (err) {
        dispatch(fetchProductsError(err));
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [])
```

**Shop.js**

```js
const mapState = ({ products }) => ({
  products: products.products,
  pending: products.pending
});

const Shop = props => {
  const { products, pending } = useSelector(mapState);

    return (
      <>
          <div className="row">
            {products.map((item, index) => {
              console.log(item)
              return (
                <ShopItems
                  name={item.name}
                  price={item.price}
                  key={index}
                  id={item.id}
                  url={item.url}
                />
              );
            })}
</>
```

**ShopItems.js**

```js
const ShopItems = props => {
    return (
       <div className="article">
           <Link className="items" to={`/article/${props.id}`}>
           <img className="itemPicture" src={props.url} alt=""/>
           <h6>{props.name}</h6>
           <h6>{props.price}€</h6>
           </Link>
       </div>
    )
}
```

Now my Redux code

**Actions.js**

```
export function fetchProductsPending() {
    return {
        type: productTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_PENDING
    }
}

export function fetchProductsSuccess(products) {
    return {
        type: productTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
        payload: products
    }
}

export function fetchProductsError(error) {
    return {
        type: productTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_ERROR,
        payload: error
    }
}
```

**Reducer.js**

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    pending: false,
    products: [],
    error: null
}

export function productsReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case productTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_PENDING: 
            return {
                ...state,
                pending: true
            }
        case productTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                pending: false,
                products: action.payload
            }
        case productTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                pending: false,
                error: action.error
            }
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```